# How to check the host and target on the same network?

Tags: networking, tcp, subnet, rtos, qnx

I want to connect a *QNX Neutrino* RTOS machine (target) to the network and my
development machine (consists of *QNX Momentics* IDE) should also be on the same network. Please tell me the steps to verify that both host and target are on the same network?

Comment: Looks remarkably line the recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751209/how-to-make-the-networking-between-the-host-and-the-target.  That got closed as I imagine this will for the same reasons, but I added a comment with links to appropriate forums and relevant documentation.

Comment: In fact that question has suspiciously similar typographical idiosyncrasies (before this was edited) and language.  Creating a new user ID and asking the same question again is not good form.

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure that you have `io-pkt` running on your target:

   ```
   pidin arg | grep io-pkt
   ```

   You should have a line similar to the following (there are multiple variants of io-pkt and any of them should be OK):

   ```
   12966 io-pkt-v4-hc -ptcpip
   ```

   If io-pkt is not running then look into your .build file in the BSP and uncomment the relevant lines or look into your BSP documentation regarding the correct driver to use and a sample command-line.

   Assuming that io-pkt is running, verify your IP address and netmask on the target. Type this:

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```

   and get something similar to:

   ```
   lo0: [parameters of the loopback interface;
         if you don't see this interface then
         check again that io-pkt is running at all]

   en0: flags=...........
        address:.........
        media:...........
        status: active
        inet 192.168.1.3 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
   ```

   In the example above `en0` is the name of the interface.  The name usually depends on the driver and may be different.  The important line is the one starting with `inet`.  It describes your TCP settings.  The IP address (`192.168.1.3` in the sample) logical AND-ed with the netmask (`0xffffff00`) in the example above should be identical with the result of logical AND-ing the IP address of your host with the netmask of your host.  How to check these parameters on the host is OS-specific but one way is to use the `ipconfig` command on Windows and `ifconfig` on the other supported hosts.


   Please note that you will need the IP-address of the target if you want to connect to it via the IDE or any other network-based method and if you did not already know it then there was no way for you to connect.

   It is a good idea to verify connectivity between your host and target via `ping` if you are having connectivity issues as you apparently do.